# Change the order of values in content type field in the forms (.aspx)

Tags: content-type, column, edit-form, newform

I have a document library with documents sets. It contains a few content types. And when I upload a document I get the form with the fields, e.g:

```
Content Type: It,HR,Document,CV
Title
etc
```

The Content Cype Field has 'CV' as the default value. I would like to set 'Document' as the default value. How can I change the order of values in Content type Field that is diplayed in new/edit forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to List Settings -> Click on Change new button order and default content type.

You can control the order with **Position from Top**:
[image]

Comment: sorry but that shows only the order of content types. what I need to change is this: the `field` called `Content Type` is displayed as dropdown with the following values: `It,HR,Document,CV`. I would like to set Document as default value in the dropdown list.

Comment: The first content type will be the default content type. So keep the order of Document as 1. It will be automatically set to default.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help as well. As Nadeem mentioned, once you are on the library follow these steps: `Library Settings -> click on 'Change the new button order and default content type'`.

If your content type is not selected, then selected it and choose the order number then click on OK. Click again on 'Change the new button order and default content' and remove the check on the content type. The order will still remain.